# Android field cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

For some reason when I am trying to define an onclick listener for the button `ButtonAddItem` and then try to add a call method that uses the EditText `EditTextAddItem`I get an error

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
EditTextAddItem cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

//full code here

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //variables
        EditText EditTextAddItem;
        Button ButtonAddItem;
        ListView ListItems;

    //array to store items
        ArrayList<String> ArrItems;
        ArrayAdapter<String> ArrAdapt;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //define variables
            EditTextAddItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddItem);
            ButtonAddItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddItem);
            ListItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    //set arraylist with listview
            ArrItems = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrAdapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrItems);
            ListItems.setAdapter(ArrAdapt);

    //onclick listener
            ButtonAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    addItem(this.EditTextAddItem.getText().toString());

                }
            });

//AddItems to listview method
    private void addItem(String item){
        if(item.length() > 0){
            this.ArrItems.add(item);
            this.ArrAdapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
            this.EditTextAddItem.setText("");
        }
}


        }
```

Comment: This won't compile, let alone run.  Are you intending for EditTextAddItem to be the name of a variable of type EditText?  You'll need to declare it as EditText EditTextAddItem = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextAddItem);  Also, it's customary in Java to name your variables in camel case starting with a lower-case character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to find a member `EditTextAddItem` of your OnClickListener.  You need to tell it to look in the parent class by prefacing `this` with the name of the parent class:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     addItem(MainActivity.this.EditTextAddItem.getText().toString());

}
```

Comment: Also, you can (and should) remove the `//TODO Auto-generated method stub`. since your method has a body now.  That's just a reminder to fill in the body.